# java database interface transaction layer

Tags: java, sqlite, interface

So I have the write an application (databaselayer, transactionlayer, not the applicationlayer) and part of the code was given to me (and I'm supposed to keep it likt that). However, there are interfaces that are used

Packages:

- databag
- database
- exception
- generators
- transactie (transaction)

Code I've written myself right now:

```
  Package database, class KlantDB:


  import exception.DBException;
  import java.util.*;
  import databag.Klant;
  import java.sql.Connection;
  import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
  import java.sql.ResultSet;
  import java.sql.SQLException;

     public class KlantDB {
    public Integer toevoegenKlant(Klant nieuweKlant) throws DBException {

    try (Connection conn = ConnectionManager.getConnection();) {
       try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(
        "insert into klant(naam, voornaam, geboortedatum, opmerking,           

       debetstand_limiet, actief)     
       values(?,?,?,?,?,?)",PreparedStatement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);) {
        stmt.setString(1, nieuweKlant.getNaam());
        stmt.setString(2, nieuweKlant.getVoornaam());
        stmt.setString(3, nieuweKlant.getGeboorteDatum().toString());
        stmt.setString(4, nieuweKlant.getOpmerking());
        stmt.setDouble(5, nieuweKlant.getDebetstandLimiet().doubleValue());
        byte b;
        if (nieuweKlant.isActief() == true){
            b = 1;

        }
        else{
            b = 0;
        }
        stmt.setByte(6, b);
        stmt.execute();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.getGeneratedKeys();
        return rs.getInt(1);


     } catch (SQLException sqlEx) {
        throw new DBException("SQL-exception in toevoegenKlant - statement"+   
       sqlEx);
     }
     } catch (SQLException sqlEx) {
      throw new DBException(
        "SQL-exception in toevoegenKlant - connection"+ sqlEx);
    }



     }}
```

Then I noticed:

Package transactie class KlantTrans

```
package transactie;

import databag.Klant;
import exception.ApplicationException;
import exception.DBException;


public interface KlantTrans {

/**
 * Klant toevoegen.
 *
 * @param k klant with all info that has to be added
 * @return de klant that was made (with filled in id)
 * @throws ApplicationException
 * @throws DBException
 */
public Klant klantAanmaken(Klant k) throws ApplicationException, DBException;
```

The goal is to write a simple bank application using a database, whilst using a data layer and a transaction layer. I don't get what I have to do with the interface, or why it is an interface in the first place. How do I implement the interface? Am I supposed to use it in my KlantDB class? And if so, why? It's clearly the database layer, not the transaction layer so I don't quite understand. SOrry if this is confusing...

Comment: This is something you should ask thes designer of the application. It cannot be answered with a general rule at SO.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose Well how could I use that interface in my other class, since it's on a higher layer?